# How to combine a large number of hashes into a sorted single Array of Hashes?

Tags: ruby

I have a generated a collection of hashes from an Excel Spreadsheet, containing users arranged by their assigned 'level' number.

```
user_data = [
  {"1st Level"=>"test@gmail.com", "2nd Level"=>"test@hotmail.com", "3rd Level"=>"test@yahoo.com"},
  {"1st Level"=>"test2@gmail.com", "2nd Level"=>"test2@hotmail.com", "3rd Level"=>"test@yahoo.com"},
  {"1st Level"=>"test2@gmail.com", "2nd Level"=>nil, "3rd Level"=>"test@yahoo.com"},
  {"1st Level"=>"test3@gmail.com", "2nd Level"=>"test3@hotmail.com", "3rd Level"=>"test4@yahoo.com"}
]
```

I'm attempting to instead have the data displayed as below, in a single Array of hashes, sorted via the Level Key, and with any K:V Pair containing a Nil Value removed. however I'm struggling to figure out how this is best done with a collection of hashes, any advice appreciated:

```
new_data = [
  { "1st Level" => "test@gmail.com" },
  { "1st Level" => "test2@gmail.com" },
  { "1st Level" => "test3@gmail.com" },

  { "2nd Level" => "test@gmail.com" },
  { "2nd Level" => "test2@gmail.com" },
  { "2nd Level" => "test3@gmail.com" },

  { "3rd Level" => "test@gmail.com" },
  { "3rd Level" => "test2@gmail.com" },
  { "3rd Level" => "test3@gmail.com" },
]
```

EDIT with context:

```
def generate_list
  data = Roo::Spreadsheet.open('test.file')
  headers = data.row(1)
  data.each_with_index do |row, idx|
    next if idx.zero?
    user_data = Hash[[headers, row].transpose]
    puts user_data.compact
  end
end
```

Comment: `{ "test@gmail.com", level: 1}` is not a valid object. Is that supposed to be an array, or a hash, or what?

Comment: `data`, as you described it, is *also* not a valid object. I suppose that's supposed to be an array of hashes, not three different objects, but your syntax isn't clear.

Comment: There are many ways you might try to "group" the data - e.g. `{"1st Level" => ["test@gmail.com", "test2@gmail.com", "test3@gmail.com"], "2nd Level" => [...], "3rd Level" => [...]}`. But you need to specify this properly in the question, otherwise it's ambiguous and confusing.

Comment: @TomLord You're right, it was terribly formatted and not correct in what I'm aiming for, I've added some context as to how it's generated currently and what my desired output structure would be.

Comment: The way you've now defined `new_data` is really weird, no?! That doesn't look like a very useful data structure... I mean, I can answer the question exactly how you described it if it's really want you want, but I'm not convinced you've thought this through carefully about what data structure you're actually aiming for.

Comment: I assumed you would have wanted to "group" things somehow

Comment: @TomLord Yes it's a weird way of outputting it, but it is how I intend.

Comment: You have `user_data = h1.h2.h3.h4`, where each `h` is a hash. That doesn't make sense (`Hash` has no instance method `.`). Please test that your data is valid before posting.

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this:

```
def generate_list
    data = Roo::Spreadsheet.open('test.file') 
    headers = data.row(1)
    user_data = {}
    data.each_with_index do |row, idx|
      next if idx.zero? 
      headers.each_with_index do |header, idx2|
        user_data[header] ||= []
        user_data[header] << row[idx2] unless row[idx2].nil?
      end
    end
    user_data
end
```

which should make something like:

```
new_data = 
{
     "1st Level"=> ["test@gmail.com","test2@gmail.com","test3@gmail.com"],
     "2nd Level"=> ["test@gmail.com","test2@gmail.com","test3@gmail.com"],
     "3rd Level"=> ["test@gmail.com","test2@gmail.com","test3@gmail.com"],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the following data:

```
user_data = [
  {"1st Level"=>"test@gmail.com", "2nd Level"=>"test@hotmail.com", "3rd Level"=>"test@yahoo.com"},
  {"1st Level"=>"test2@gmail.com", "2nd Level"=>"test2@hotmail.com", "3rd Level"=>"test@yahoo.com"},
  {"1st Level"=>"test2@gmail.com", "2nd Level"=>nil, "3rd Level"=>"test@yahoo.com"},
  {"1st Level"=>"test3@gmail.com", "2nd Level"=>"test3@hotmail.com", "3rd Level"=>"test4@yahoo.com"}
]
```

We can apply this transformation:

```
new_data = user_data.flat_map do |element|
  element.compact.map { |level, email| { level => email } }
end
```

To get the result you described:

```
new_data = [
  {"1st Level"=>"test@gmail.com"},
  {"2nd Level"=>"test@hotmail.com"},
  {"3rd Level"=>"test@yahoo.com"},
  {"1st Level"=>"test2@gmail.com"},
  {"2nd Level"=>"test2@hotmail.com"},
  {"3rd Level"=>"test@yahoo.com"},
  {"1st Level"=>"test2@gmail.com"},
  {"3rd Level"=>"test@yahoo.com"},
  {"1st Level"=>"test3@gmail.com"},
  {"2nd Level"=>"test3@hotmail.com"},
  {"3rd Level"=>"test4@yahoo.com"}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the provided `user_data` array:

```
user_data = [
  {"1st Level"=>"test@gmail.com", "2nd Level"=>"test@hotmail.com", "3rd Level"=>"test@yahoo.com"},
  {"1st Level"=>"test2@gmail.com", "2nd Level"=>"test2@hotmail.com", "3rd Level"=>"test@yahoo.com"},
  {"1st Level"=>"test2@gmail.com", "2nd Level"=>nil, "3rd Level"=>"test@yahoo.com"},
  {"1st Level"=>"test3@gmail.com", "2nd Level"=>"test3@hotmail.com", "3rd Level"=>"test4@yahoo.com"}
]
```

using the following code:

```
new_data = Array.new
keys = user_data.first.keys
keys.each do |key|
    user_data.each do |item|
        new_data << {key => item["1st Level"]} unless item[key].nil?
    end
end
new_data.uniq
```

produced the sample output:

```
=>[{"1st Level"=>"test@gmail.com"}, 
{"1st Level"=>"test2@gmail.com"}, 
{"1st Level"=>"test3@gmail.com"}, 
{"2nd Level"=>"test@gmail.com"}, 
{"2nd Level"=>"test2@gmail.com"}, 
{"2nd Level"=>"test3@gmail.com"}, 
{"3rd Level"=>"test@gmail.com"}, 
{"3rd Level"=>"test2@gmail.com"}, 
{"3rd Level"=>"test3@gmail.com"}]
```

However, your output description suggests an output more like:

```
=>[{"1st Level"=>"test@gmail.com"}, 
{"1st Level"=>"test2@gmail.com"}, 
{"1st Level"=>"test3@gmail.com"}, 
{"2nd Level"=>"test@hotmail.com"}, 
{"2nd Level"=>"test2@hotmail.com"}, 
{"2nd Level"=>"test3@hotmail.com"}, 
{"3rd Level"=>"test@yahoo.com"}, 
{"3rd Level"=>"test4@yahoo.com"}]
```

which was produced by this code:

```
new_data2 = Array.new
keys = user_data.first.keys
keys.each do |key|
    user_data.each do |item|
        new_data2 << {key => item[key]} unless item[key].nil?
    end
end
new_data2.uniq
```