# Adding new keys to a Array Of Hashes

Tags: ruby

I have a collection of K:V Pairs as seen below:

```
list = [

{"Mary"=>"Die Hard"},
{"Paul"=>"The Grinch"},
{"John"=>"Halloween"},

]
```

But now I would like to flesh out and change the list, adding more specific keys in order to make it more searchable.

Is this possible or even an advisable way to go about this?

```
new_list = [

 { name: "Mary", film: "Die Hard"},
 { name: "Paul", film: "The Grinch"},
 { name: "John", film: "Halloween"},

]
```

Comment: _"a collection of K:V Pairs"_ – that describes a hash. You have an array of hashes, each containing a single key-value pair. (which is why the conversion is slightly more complicated)

Comment: I'm going to assume this is a follow-up to [the question you asked earlier today, which I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70754617/how-to-combine-a-large-number-of-hashes-into-a-sorted-single-array-of-hashes).

Comment: You could use my original answer to your original question by replacing `{ level => email } ` with `{ level: level, email: email }`.

Comment: You've also got to appreciate the irony that in the original question, I said *"...That doesn't look like a very useful data structure... I mean, I can answer the question exactly how you described it if it's really want you want..."* -- and here we are a few hours later with a request for a different data structure 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably:

1. Use [`map`](https://rubyapi.org/3.1/o/enumerable#method-i-map) to iterate over the elements in `list` and build a new array at the same time
2. Since each element is a hash with one item, destruct that into a key and value
3. Build the new hash in the correct format

```
new_list = list.map do |hash|
  # e.g. key = "Mary", value = "Die Hard"
  key, value = hash.first

  {name: key, film: value}
end
```

This assumes that each hash in the list will have only one item (as you've shown in your example in the question) - you may want to validate this elsewhere, since this solution would ignore any other items in the hash past the first.